# jboss EAP v/s Widfly differences

Tags: wildfly, redhat, jboss-eap-6, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I am curious to know that are there any functional differences in Redhat Jboss EAP and community Wildfly. Is there something extra in EAP which is not available in Jboss wildfly.

I am using OpenShift origin with openshift wildfly centos based image. So thought of getting to know this in detail because origin doesnt provide EAP image.

Comment: what version of EAP, what version of WildFly

Comment: @ctomc its EAP and Wildfly 7, could you please tell me functional differences now?

Comment: you mean EAP7 and WildFly 10? as there is no such thing as WildFly 7, there was JBoss AS 7 project that was renamed to WildFly with version 8.

Comment: @ctomc: sorry actually its wildfly8

Answer (score 0):

WildFly is the community stream for JBoss EAP 7. Have a look at http://wildfly.org/governance/.